# Is neutral wire being switched?

Tags: wiring

I'm replacing a light fixture with a ceiling fan and there's a black, white, and ground wire in the ceiling box (each branched off of a cluster of wires that continue on to power the wall outlets). But when I turn the wall switch off, the black wire still is detected as live by my multi-meter. Note that the wall outlets are always on, regardless of whether the wall switch is on or off, but the light would turn on and off with the switch.

The multimeter measures no voltage between the black and white when the switch is off (but does measure voltage when when it's on).

I don't know much about wiring, but does this mean the neutral wire is being switched, and is it dangerous to hook up the fan anyway?

Comment: Usually you switch live and keep neutral connected, or you switch both at once. There's exceptions to that. Since grad voltage can hurt and kill, maybe just call an electrician.

Comment: If you are testing correctly, the neutral is being switched. However if you are describing the situation accurately, the switch seems to be switching the wall outlets also. You should probably call an electrician.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside both the fan and switch boxes please?

Comment: Is the switch you are referring to a wall switch or is it the pull chain switch located in the fan?

Comment: thanks for the comments! I've updated the description to clarify: the outlets stay on, and the switch was referring to the wall switch. I've got the fan attached at this point, and everything seems to be working...however I'm still a little skeptical that they had the light switch wired backwards, and now so do I with the fan.

Comment: Is there only one wall switch that controls the light in question? When you have multiple wall switches controlling the same circuit, depending on the exact status of all the switches, the white wire may actually be hot.

Comment: ah good point, but yep it's just a single on/off switch, no other one involved

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: sure, i'll try to get a photo of that this evening